# JDBC getColumnDisplaySize always returns zero

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, database-metadata

I am using `ResultSetMetadata.getColumnDisplaySize` to get the column display size but it always returns zero.
What can be the reason for that. Is there an alternative way to get the correct size?
thanks.

```
private List<Column> getColumns(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();

        for(int i =1; i<= columnCount; i++) {
            Column column = new Column();
            column.setName(md.getColumnLabel(i));
            column.setDataType(md.getColumnTypeName(i));
            column.setSize(md.getColumnDisplaySize(i));
            columns.add(column);
        }

        return columns;
    }
```

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Comment: tried in oracle and mysql

Comment: Drivers sometimes return 0 when they simply don't know how to return a proper size. What is the type of the database column ?

Comment: Does your table have any data in it? I recall having problems like this for tables without data.

Comment: they are number, date and varchar2. btw  there is a similar discussion in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/Gjwkqo095ew. I do have data but i do not iterate with resultset. I just want to get metadata.